# What is the Linux equivalent command for the Windows ipconfig /registerdns command?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dhcp

In Windows one can run

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

and [this refreshes all Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) address leases and registers all related domain names that the client computer configures and uses with the dynamic DNS server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc794946%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

What's the command for doing the same thing(s) in Linux?

Comment: There isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is "dhclient"

The DHCP client in Linux is called dhclient. It requests dynamic IP addresses from the DHCP server, which "leases" addresses to clients for a set amount of time. dhclient can be invoked manually to "release" the client's currently assigned IP address, and get another address from the DHCP server.

Comment: runnig dhclient command itself direclty will solve this?? or do we need to add anything

Comment: yes. it will "release" the client's currently assigned IP address, and get another address from the DHCP server